# How use vlookup in ms excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel work book with three work sheets as bellow,

[image]

above sheet contains all the sales details (i.e. Colombo(city or region)) for each month and the names of each sales persons, there is another sheet like this as collections in the same format to record collected cash amounts

[image]

in the above sheet the column header is a drop down list which user can select either sales or collection.

What I need to happen is when user selects sales or collection from the drop down appropriate data should be displayed against each sales person's name, year and month should be able to change too. Amal, Kamal, Nuwan, etc. are the names of each sales persons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the total line from a name:

```
=VLOOKUP(NAME, A:N, 14, FALSE)
```

should do it, where `NAME` is the name to look up, `A:N` is the lookup table.

Comment: what does '14' means in this function?

Comment: 14 is the distance between column `A` (the key column) and column `N` (the value column).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a pivot table. If you haven't used them before, pivot tables are the backbone of analytics where you can through data viewpoints around all of your data points. They allow you to take a flatfile sheet of data and manipulate it across multiple axes. Here's some links on the topic.

[Learn to use pibot tables](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/chunkers/learn_to_use_pivot_tables_in_excel_2007_to_organize_data)

[Youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zHLnUCtfUk)

For your needs, you can create multiple worksheets with pivot tables for each salesperson, or each period of time, or sales region, or any other KPI or datapoint. When you update the source data, the pivot tables can be refreshed and keep in sync without any extra handling or manipulation from you.